# Cancelling task in C#

Tags: c#

I have a Form with two buttons (**Start** , **Stop**).

When I press **Start** Button a **Task** is initialized and a function is called that keeps running until **Stop** button is pressed.

But When I press **Stop** button Form freezes. why?
I have copied snippet from [StackOverflow](http://Stackoverflow.com/) but it still freezes Form.
So tell me how to Cancel Task properly?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private Task _task;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Funtion that runs when Task is initialized.
    private void EventLoop(CancellationToken token)
    { 
        //Code here..
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //Code here..
        }
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Operation Complete..!!");
        }

    }

    //Function for Start Button.
    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => EventLoop(_cts.Token), _cts.Token);
    }

    //Function for Stop button.
    private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         _cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Similar Example from MSDN:

```
var compute = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    return SumRootN(j);
}, tokenSource.Token);`
```

Form After **Stop** button is pressed.
`token.IsCancellationRequested` is **true** .

[image: Freeze Form]

Full `EventLoop()` Function.

```
private void EventLoop(CancellationToken token)
    {
        SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
        string text, batch, part, courseName;
        text = batch = part = courseName = "";
        int courseId = 0;

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
        {
            text = portCB.SelectedItem.ToString();
            batch = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            part = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();
            courseName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            progressBar1.Value = 20;
            using (Model1 db = new Model1())
            {
                courseId = db.Courses.Where(c => c.Course_name.ToUpper() == courseName.ToUpper()).Select(c => c.Course_Id).Single();
            }
        });

        sp.PortName = text;
        sp.BaudRate = 9600;
        sp.Open();

        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            text = sp.ReadLine();

            if (text.Contains("Found ID #"))
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    textBox2.Clear();
                    textBox2.Text = "Getting Registation ID.\n";
                    progressBar1.Value = 60;
                });

                string splitText = text.Split('#')[1];
                int end = splitText.IndexOf(' ');
                int id = int.Parse(splitText.Substring(0, end));

                using (Model1 db = new Model1())
                {
                    var result = db.Students.Where(s => s.Reg_Id == id && s.Batch == batch && s.Class == part).Select(s => s).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        Attendance a = new Attendance();
                        a.Course_Id = courseId;
                        a.Student_Id = id;
                        a.Status = "P";
                        a.Date = DateTime.Today.Date;
                        a.Batch = batch;
                        a.Part = part;

                        db.Attendances.Add(a);
                        string message = "";

                        if (db.SaveChanges() != 0)
                        {
                            message = "Attendance Uploaded..!!\n";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            message = "Attendance Not Uploaded ..!!\n";
                        }

                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                        {
                            progressBar1.Value = 100;
                            textBox2.AppendText(message);
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                        {
                            textBox2.AppendText("Student Does not belong to Specified Batch Or Part..\n");
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    textBox2.AppendText("No Match Found..!! \n");
                });
            }
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
             {
                 textBox1.AppendText(text + "\n");
             });
        }
        sp.Close();

        // This exception will be handled by the Task
        // and will not cause the program to crash
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Operation Comptele..!!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is obviously very, very untidy, but I'm not seeing anything that would cause a deadlock. Sure you're not registering a cancellation callback on the `CancellationToken` or calling `_task.Wait`/`_task.Result` anywhere?

Comment: no am not doing anything else other than Enabling and disabling CheckBoxes in **Start**  And **Stop** Button Codding.. i can show you but  then everyone will downvote my question..

Comment: The form in the screenshot is clearly disabled, but I'm not seeing the form's `Enabled` property being set anywhere in the code, so I'm inclined to think the problem occurs in the part of the code that hasn't been posted.

Comment: your code example should, indeed, be minimal - but it should also be complete. You could, for instance, start removing bits of code until you have the bare minimum left to demonstrate the problem. Chances are, by then you would have found the solution on your own.

Comment: Move the database access code from the `Invoke` call.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy , upon minimizing Code i came to know that form is being  disabled on stop button click. i accidentally  wrote `this.Enabled = false` instead of `this.Stop.Enabled = false` . now it is working. thanks.

Comment: In any case, move out all the heavy code from the `Invoke` call! Because `Invoke` is executed in the UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `MessageBox.Show("Operation Complete..!!");` in the progress of cancellation. This is highly not recommended, not talking about that you are calling an UI operation from other than the UI thread.

Comment the `MessageBox.Show("Operation Complete..!!");` line out

*** Edit ***

Question author's comment on his original question, found the mistake, which line was removed from the post. Here are my conclusion:

*Always* try to isolate an issue, and reproduce in its *purest* form. During that process you will probably diagnose and find the issues itself :-).

So if the code with issue is long to post, it is definitely not the way just deleting lines then post it. The way is deleting lines and see if the issue exist, with other words: Isolating the issue in its purest reproducable form

Comment: I have Commented it out but still form freezes.

Comment: Could you please post the code within the while loop?

Comment: its very lengthy...  and i dont wanna get Negative votes , already on the edge of being banned. But i will take risk..

Comment: OK, anyway I've tried to reproduce the issue using exactly the code you posted and I can not, all works fine. Is there any code in the Task which executed when the cancel signal is received?

Comment: i have added full `Eventloop()` function in question.. see if you can identify the problem.

Answer (score -1):

please use async call on your task

```
  private async void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => EventLoop(_cts.Token), _cts.Token);
        await task;       
  }
```